# Update sqlite table with html table contents

Tags: javascript, php, sqlite

Given a html table where each cell is a text input, with the push of one button, have the table be written to a sqlite table. The objective is to have a table that a user can update cell values for online and then have those changes saved to the sqlite .db file on the hosting computer.

```
    <!-- THIS IS THE BUTTON -->

    <form method="post" action= "file.php">

    <!-- THIS IS THE IMPUT TABLE -->

    <div class="row"><center>
            <?php
            $id = "myTable";
            $count = 0;
            echo "<table id=".$id.">\n\n"; 
            $f = fopen($tableCSV, "r"); 
            while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
                echo "<tr>";
                foreach ($line as $cell) {
                    if ($count != 0) {
                        echo "<td><input value=" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "></input></td>";
                    } else {
                        echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
                    }    
                }
            echo "</tr>\n";
            $count += 1;
            }
            fclose($f); echo "\n</table>";
        }
        ?>

    </center></div>
```

Comment: So... What exactly is your problem?

Comment: I need to take the table (after it may have been edited by a user) and get all of its cell info into an array of arrays which can then be sent to be processed. Im having trouble getting the arrays.

Comment: That's not how the `action` attribute works. You specify a page for the forum to post back to; you can't specify PHP code like that.

Comment: Edited to fix that. I guess now I just don't understand how to get the table data to go to the file.php that the action specifies